# Wordpress; displaying all images from a post with their corresponding captions

Tags: php, wordpress

From any specific Post, I am trying to display all images, with their corresponding captions and arrange them one after the other like:

```
-------------
|           |
|    Img1   |
|           |
-------------
  Caption 1    

-------------
|           |
|    Img2   |
|           |
-------------
  Caption 2        

-------------
|           |
|    Img3   |
|           |
-------------
  Caption 3
```

THAT IS WHAT I WANT TO ACHIEVE.

The code:

```
<?php

$attachments = get_children( array(
'post_parent' => get_the_ID(), 
'order' => 'ASC', 
'post_mime_type' =>'image') );

$args = array(
'post_parent' => get_the_ID(),  
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'post_type' => 'attachment' ); 

$thumb_images = get_posts($args);


foreach ($attachments as $attachment_id => $attachment)  

foreach ($thumb_images as $thumb_image) 

{
{
  echo "<div class='image'>";
  echo wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment_id, 'full' );
  echo "</div>";
  echo "<div class='caption'>";  
  echo $thumb_image->post_excerpt;
  echo "</div>";
}
}

?>
```

If there are 3 images & their corresponding captions,   this code displays 3 times each image,  and each one with the 3 different captions.   That is 9 images & 9 captions.   At least the captions are in order, but images repeat.

```
-------------
|           |
|    Img1   |
|           |
-------------
 Caption 1    

-------------
|           |
|    Img1   |
|           |
-------------
 Caption 2        

-------------
|           |
|    Img1   |
|           |
-------------
 Caption 3


-------------
|           |
|    Img2   |
|           |
-------------
  Caption 1    

-------------
|           |
|    Img2   |
|           |
-------------
  Caption 2        

-------------
|           |
|    Img2   |
|           |
-------------
  Caption 3            


  ETC
```

IF THE CODE IS UPDATED TO:

```
   <?php

$attachments = get_children( array(
'post_parent' => get_the_ID(), 
'order' => 'ASC', 
'post_mime_type' =>'image') );

$args = array(
'post_parent' => get_the_ID(),  
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'post_type' => 'attachment' ); 

$thumb_images = get_posts($args);


foreach ($attachments as $attachment_id => $attachment)   {

foreach ($thumb_images as $thumb_image)     {}  


  echo "<div class='image'>";
  echo wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment_id, 'full' );
  echo "</div>";
  echo "<div class='caption'>";  
  echo $thumb_image->post_excerpt;
  echo "</div>";

}

?>
```

It displays the images without repetitions,  but the caption belongs to the last image that was loaded and repeats the equivalent to the total amount of images associated with the post.

```
-------------
|           |
|    Img1   |
|           |
-------------
  Caption 3    

-------------
|           |
|    Img2   |
|           |
-------------
  Caption 3        

-------------
|           |
|    Img3   |
|           |
-------------
  Caption 3
```

Any idea on how to write it correctly, so that you end with x times the number of images and x times the number of captions one after the other?   Without repetitions.

Best regards.

Laura

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `$attachments` is the same size as `$thumb_images`:

```
$i = 0;
foreach ($attachments as $attachment_id => $attachment) {
    echo "<div class='image'>";
    echo wp_get_attachment_image($attachment_id, 'full');
    echo "</div>";
    echo "<div class='caption'>";  
    echo $thumb_images[$i]->post_excerpt;
    echo "</div>";
    $i++;
}
```

To have a better understanding of what's in `$attachments` and `$thumb_images`, use the following code snippet for debugging:

```
echo "<pre>";
echo var_dump($attachments);
echo var_dump($thumb_images);
echo "</pre>";
```

You'll find that `$thumb_images` is an array.

**Q: What is the logic of `$i++`?**

`$i++` is the [post-increment operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.increment.php).

`$i++` is really shorthand for `$i = $i + 1`, so for each iteration of the loop, the value of `$i` increments. Initially, `$i = 0`. Once `$i++` is called, `$i = 1`. If `$i++` is called again on another iteration, `$i = 2` and so on and so forth.

Instead of using a `foreach` loop, you can also use a `for` loop to iterate over arrays. For examples of the `for` loop (and correspondingly examples that use the `$i++` concept), see [PHP's documentation for `for`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php).

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer, I appreciate it.   I've just tested it but it returns only the images, no captions at all.   I get that same result when using:     foreach ($attachments as $attachment_id => $attachment)  {
 {
 echo "<div class='image'>";
    echo wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment_id, 'full' );
    echo "</div>";
 
 echo "<div class='caption'>";  }
    echo $thumb_image->post_excerpt; 
    echo "</div>";
 }

Comment: IT WORKS,  $thumb_images[$i] was missing from my test!   What is the logic of $i++?   Thanks again for your time.

Comment: Awesome, now works as it should.   I am still a beginner on this, once again thank you for your time it was really helpful!